# how did they expand the following function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am reading a book and came across an expansion of a function. Here is a picture to better understand what I am saying.[image]

I am trying to figure out how did they expand the functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ this way.

Comment: What book is this from?

Comment: What are γ and δ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a technique known as [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition). The basic idea is that if $a,b,\gamma,\delta$ are real numbers, then
$$
\frac a{\gamma-x} +\frac b{\delta -x}=\frac{a(\delta-x)+b(\gamma-x)}{(\gamma-x)(\delta-x)}
$$
This is often used from left to right, and in that case it's called "addition of fractions". However, it can also be used from right to left. In that case it's called partial fraction decomposition.

You have to factor $x^2-3x+1$ first to find $\gamma$ and $\delta$ so that $x^2-3x+1=(\gamma-x)(\delta-x)$. Once you've done that, you can find $a$ and $b$ from $a(\gamma-x)+b(\delta-x)=1-x$ in the case of $f$, and $a(\gamma-x)+b(\delta-x)=x$ in the case of $g$.